# Do [T]EE and [T]BE have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transformation, change-of-basis

I know there are plenty of questions regarding 2 matrices one is [T]BB and one is [T]EE , so we all know that eigenvalues and eigenvectors are kept across different bases.

My question is what happens when you have a transformation from one basis to another are the eigenvalues kept the same ?

For example i have one matrix that gets vectors relative to base B and the image is returned according to base E would its eigenvalues be exactly the same as the same transformation from E to E?

Comment: What is the relationship between the two matrices?  What happens when you compute the characteristic polynomial of two matrices related that way?

Comment: Hint: $[I]_B^E$, where $I$ is the identity transformation, can be made into any invertible matrix with an appropriate choice of basis $B$.

Comment: Didnt get your hints. Could you respond? Btw I am talking about T from b to e

Comment: @bilanush If you want someone's attention, you should tag them (as I have you), otherwise the SE software doesn't notify them that you've replied. Anyway, the point was, the identity operator has only the eigenvalue $1$, whereas invertible matrices can have any list of non-zero eigenvalues. So, this operation cannot preserve eigenvalues. Indeed, if you let $B$ be the double length standard basis (i.e. the basis consisting of the standard basis vectors, all multiplied by $2$), then $[I]_B^E = 2I$, which has only the eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: @Theo Bendit thx. What if I specifically ask from B to E?  That's the image falls is the standard basis.

Comment: @bilanush I may have messed up the notation, but my example was from $B$ to $E$. That is, the transformation matrix from "double-standard" basis $B$ to $E$ will be $2I$. That said, doing it the other way gives $\frac{1}{2} I$. In both directions, the eigenvalues change!

Comment: @Theo Bendit dont get your answer bro.  Would be happy if you show me a counterexample.  I dont care about this double or 1/2. Just give me a counter example  of b to e different eigenvalues than e to e

Answer (score 1):

Here's the counterexample from the comments explicitly.

Let $E = ((1, 0), (0, 1))$ be the standard basis and let $B = ((2, 0), (0, 2))$. Clearly $B$ is a basis too.

Let $I_{\Bbb{R}^2}$ be the identity operator on $\Bbb{R}^2$. We now compute $\left[I_{\Bbb{R}^2}\right]_B^E$, by which I mean, the matrix for $I_{\Bbb{R}^2}$ from basis $B$ to $E$, i.e. the unique matrix $M$ such that $M[v]_B = \left[I_{\Bbb{R}^2} v\right]_E = [v]_E$ (this is also known as the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $E$).

To compute this, we transform the basis vectors in $B$ by $I_{\Bbb{R}^2}$, and express them as linear combinations of $E$. Computing,
\begin{align*}
I_{\Bbb{R}^2}(2, 0) = (2, 0) = 2(1, 0) + 0(0, 1) &\implies \left[I_{\Bbb{R}^2}(2, 0)\right]_E = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \\
I_{\Bbb{R}^2}(0, 2) = (0, 2) = 0(1, 0) + 2(0, 1) &\implies \left[I_{\Bbb{R}^2}(0, 2)\right]_E = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
These columns combine to give us
$$\left[I_{\Bbb{R}^2}\right]_B^E = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} = 2I_{2 \times 2}.$$

Now, what are the eigenvalues for this matrix? It shouldn't be difficult to see that $2I_{2 \times 2} - \lambda I_{2 \times 2}$ is singular if and only if $\lambda = 2$ (otherwise the inverse matrix is $(2 - \lambda)^{-1}I_{2 \times 2}$). So, the one and only eigenvalue is $2$. Note how this differs from $I_{\mathbb{R}^2}$: its only eigenvalue was $1$. This completes the counterexample.

---

To expand on my first hint, you can actually make $\left[I_{\Bbb{R}^2}\right]_B^E$ be equal to any invertible matrix you want. All you do is set $B$ to be the columns of your matrix. As the matrix is invertible, the columns form a basis. It's easy enough to see, using the above process, that the result just gives you back the matrix you started with.

So, if your conjecture were true, then it would have to be the case that every invertible matrix has only $\lambda = 1$ as an eigenvalue. Finding even a single example of an invertible matrix without $\lambda = 1$ as its only eigenvalue (which I did with $2I_{2 \times 2}$) will therefore lead to a counterexample.

---

EDIT: In response to the comments below.

You're so very close to being right here, that it will make it tricky for me to explain.

I am dealing with two types of objects here: operators and square matrices. In the above answer, $I_{\Bbb{R}^2}$ is an example of the former, while $I_{2 \times 2}$ is an example of the latter. These objects both have eigenvalues, but have very *slightly* different notions of eigenvectors.

If $T$ is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then eigenvectors, corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, is an abstract vector $v \in V$ such that $T(v) = \lambda v$. Maybe $v$ is a polynomial, a vector, or possibly a matrix. It's an abstract vector, to which we **apply** $T$, and we get back the parallel abstract vector $\lambda v$.

If $M$ is a square matrix, then an eigenvector $v$ of $M$ are now (coordinate) column vectors, with entries from the scalar field. We have a similar equation $Mv = \lambda v$, but now $Mv$ is **matrix multiplication** between two compatibly-sized matrices, not applying an operator to an abstract vector to get another abstract vector.

Now, we have a way of transforming an operator $T$ on an $n$-dimensional space over a field $\Bbb{F}$ into an $n \times n$ matrix $M$, using a basis $B$. This $M$ has the special property that $[T(v)]_B = M[v]_B$ for all $v \in V$, where $[ \cdot ]_B$ is the coordinate vector with respect to $B$. We call this $M$, $[T]_B$, or perhaps $[T]^B_B$, or indeed any number of other notations. Note that it depends on the basis $B$.

It is not difficult to see that
$$T(v) = \lambda v \iff [T]^B_B[v]_B = \lambda [v]_B.$$
This implies that, the eigenvalues of $T$ and $[T]_B^B$ are indeed the same. Note that this doesn't depend on the basis $B$ at all, so no matter what basis you choose, the eigenvalues will be perfectly preserved.

The eigenvectors, on the other hand, are not the same, but are still closely related. An abstract vector $v \in V$ is an eigenvector of the operator $T$ if and only if the column vector $[v]_B$ is an eigenvector of the matrix $[T]_B^B$. In this way, we see that the eigenspace of matrices $[T]_B^B$ and $[T]_E^E$ are actually potentially completely different. They represent the same set of arbitrary vectors in $V$, but they will produce totally different column vectors in $\Bbb{F}^{n \times 1}$.

Now, in our setting, it's a bit more complicated still. We are starting in one basis, and finishing in another. Our eigenvalue/vector equation, in terms of abstract vectors and operators, becomes
$$[T]_B^E[v]_B = \lambda [v]_E$$
when we try to use the matrix $[T]_B^E$. But, note that the two column vectors $[v]_B$ and $[v]_E$ could be totally different. There is no reason to think that the eigenvalues are the same, and no reason to think that there will be any correspondence between the eigenvectors.

So, you are right that the operator $I_{\Bbb{R}^2}$ on the (not so) abstract vector space $\Bbb{R}^2$ has eigenvectors independent of basis. As per your question, we changed it into a matrix, though not one of the form $\left[I_{\Bbb{R}^2}\right]_B^B$. You asked about the matrix's eigenvalues and eigenvectors, which means now we are no longer considering abstract vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and the abstract operator $I_{\Bbb{R}^2}$, but instead a $2 \times 2$ matrix of real numbers. The eigenvectors are going to be column vectors in the matrix space $\Bbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$. Because we mixed the bases, there's no reason to expect the eigenvalues to be the same, or the eigenvectors to correspond.

I hope you don't disagree with my calculation of
$$\left[I_{\Bbb{R}^2}\right]_B^E = 2 I_{2 \times 2} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$
The eigenvectors of this matrix will satisfy:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}.$$
It's very easy to see that the only possible value of $\lambda$ is $2$, proving that this **matrix** (not operator) has eigenvalue $2$, which disagrees with the eigenvalues of the original **operator** on which it was based.

Comment: Nice! But they would have same eigenbasis /vectors would that always  hold true?

Comment: No, not always. By what I said in the second part of my answer, you can make this matrix any invertible matrix you wish, including matrices that have completely different eigenspaces.

Comment: Ok but sorry. I am not sure I agree with your answer.  I was wrong.  When I re think it... the transformation  from b to e which you showed  the eigenvalues  aren't  considered  2. But rather 1.   Because  what it actually  does to the base vectors? Multiply them by 1  . I dont think it's called that its eigenvalues  are 2

Comment: I thought  eigenvalues  are calculated base on real vectors  not coordinated ones

Comment: @bilanush I have responded in my answer above. It's a good point you raise, and it takes some background to properly answer.

Comment: Thx very much. Maybe this is the conclusion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205205/eigenvalues-of-a-triangular-matrix-from-one-base-to-another

Comment: Maybe your refutation  is true only when B basis isn't  made of ones and zeros

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "triangular" in that case, but I can tell you that every matrix in my example is diagonal, and hence both upper and lower triangular. So, it seems that my counterexample works for your new question too.

Comment: You are right but check what I wrote in the enclosure.  And check my new comment  here. Your example  only works in a B basis which isnt made of ones and zeros. So yup you refuted it for infinite and most cases. Now I am concerned  with only B basis made of ones and zeros. Would then my question  here be correct? I think yes.

Comment: Technically, my basis was made up of $2$s and $0$s, not $1$s and $0$s. If you want a counterexample that doesn't have any $0$s (or whatever other properties you'd like it to have), just choose **any basis you like**. Seriously, pick your favourite basis. The only basis such that $[I]_B^E$ will have the same eigenvalues and same dimension eigenspace is $B = E$. That's the *only* solution.

Comment: I am not talking  only about  the identity  I am talking  about every  matrix. If you would  compose its vectors  using only ones and zeros  then I claim the eigenvalues would  be the same. Take this basis(1,0) (1,1) . Ur eigenvalues would  also be 1, 1 in both matrices  of course.  And if you map them even to say (1,0) (2,3)  . You eigenvalues would be in both matrices 1 and 3

Comment: What about the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$? This has eigenvalues $0$ and $-2$.

Comment: What's your basis B? If you basis is just the standard basis the matrix of [T]ee and T]be would  be the same

Comment: Ugh, sorry, I temporarily forgot what I was doing. No, there is no basis that will produce that. Instead you can consider the basis $(0, 1), (1, 1)$, which produces the change of basis matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. This matrix has eigenvalues different from $1$ (irrational roots of a quadratic).

Comment: Ok not sure about that but stil intrested  about my question  here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205205/eigenvalues-of-a-triangular-matrix-from-one-base-to-another     by the way your matrix doesnt have to be only 1 and 0. It can have any numbers you wish. I only require basis B to have 1s and 0s

Comment: @bilanush Fair enough. In the specific case $[I]_B^E$, the matrix will contain the basis vectors as columns, so the $1$s and $0$s will make their way into the columns! Choosing a different matrix from $I$ could change this though.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be the identity matrix .

Comment: Any transformation you want and they could  be mapped to any vectors you want.  Just require B basis vectors to be composed of 1s and 0s