# Eigenvalues of a triangular matrix from one base to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

@Gerry Myerson in the comments bellow offered a better  formulation to my question

```
T is a linear 
transformation from, let's say,
R3 to R3. With respect to 
the standard basis, T is represented by 
a matrix we'll call  M. With respect
to the basis B on the 
domain and the 
standard basis on the codomain,
 T is represented by a 
 matrix we'll call N. We assume the
 elements of B have all 
 entries zero or one,
 and we assume N is triangular. Then 
 the question is whether M and N 
 have the same eigenvalues
```

((((
In a normal  triangular matrix its known  that its diagonal is composed of all eigenvalues.

Suppose you have a B basis made of vectors  which made of only ones and zeros

What about  a triangular matrix [T]BE that takes vectors  from base B and return the transformation in the standard base E? Would  its eigenvalues be the same as the same transformation [T]EE  the matrix which takes vectors  from E and returns the transformation also in E?

(I tried finding  a counterexample  the only counterexample I could  find is when vectors of B basis arent composed with ones and zeros. Could you find a counterexample of a base B composing of vectors apart from 1 and 0 and still having a diagonal different than its [ T]EE equivalent?)))))

Comment: The transformation matrix from $E$ to $E$ would just be the identity matrix, no? If the entries of the elements of $B$ are all zeros & ones, and $B$ is a basis, and a matrix whose columns are the elements of $B$ is triangular, then the entries on the diagonal must be ones, so the only eigenvalue is one.

Comment: Not at all . (1,1,1) (1,01) (0,0,1) . And a billion  other permutations of any degree vector space

Comment: The matrix whose columns are those three vectors is not triangular, bilan.

Comment: Oh I see maybe I wasn't  clear. I dont mean E the identity  matrix. I mean standard  basis.  Even if your basis was (100) (010) (001) no body forces you to map them to the identity.  You matrix  could  have any numbers you wish not only  ones and zeros. I force only the basis B to be composed of ones and zeros. But you are free to map them anywhere

Comment: Why isnt this matrix triangular??? I just wrote the B basis. You map them where you wish. But you must map them to vectors forming a triangular  matrix since this is the[ T]be

Comment: The transformation matrix from $E$ to $E$ is the identity matrix, certainly if $E$ is the standard basis.

Comment: Noooo.  I am not talking  about transformation  of coordinates.  I am talking  about any  transformation  you wish. But relative to which basis

Comment: The matrix whose columns are those three vectors is $$\pmatrix{1&1&0\cr1&0&0\cr1&1&1\cr}$$ *That* matrix isn't triangular.

Comment: T FROM E TO E only means you get a vector  written in E basis and you do what ever transformation  you want but you return the image in E basis as well

Comment: That's not the usual usage of the those words.

Comment: Ok so you are right I was wrong  in this specific  example.  Take this one (100) (110) (101) this should be B basis

Comment: Yes, that is a basis. And the matrix whose columns are those three vectors is triangular, with ones on its diagonal, so its only eigenvalue is one.

Comment: It doesn't  matter the basis since I stipulated  in my question  that [T]BE is triangular.  The question  is if its diagonal must be the eigenvalues  of [T]EE

Comment: But we are talking  about different  bases.  This one takes vectors  from b and outputs in e. Its diagonal  usually  wouldn't  be the same as  the eigenvalues of same transformation [ T]EE.   That's why I added requirements

Comment: OK, here's what I think you're asking. $T$ is a linear transformation from, let's say, ${\bf R}^3$ to ${\bf R}^3$. With respect to the standard basis, $T$ is represented by a matrix we'll call $M$. With respect to the basis $B$ on the domain and the standard basis on the codomain, $T$ is represented by a matrix we'll call $N$. We assume the elements of $B$ have all entries zero or one, and we assume $N$ is triangular. Then the question is whether $M$ and $N$ have the same eigenvalues. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. And so obviously  the diagonal  of N would  indicate the eigenvalues but that's obvious.

Comment: I would  copy you formulation  to the question

Comment: Is the answer I posted what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: C'mon, bilanush, you asked the question, I posted an answer – please engage with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $M$ and $N$ don't necessarily have the same eigenvalues. I'll give an example in ${\bf R}^2$.

Let $b_1=(1,1)$, $b_2=(0,1)$, $B=\{\,b_1,b_2\,\}$. Then $e_1=(1,0)=b_1-b_2$, and $e_2=(0,1)=b_2$.

Let $T:{\bf R}^2\to{\bf R}^2$ be the linear transformation given by $T(b_1)=e_1$, $T(b_2)=e_1+e_2$. Then $$N=\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}$$ has only the eigenvalue $1$.

We calculate $T(e_1)=T(b_1)-T(b_2)=e_1-(e_1+e_2)=-e_2$, and $T(e_2)=T(b_2)=e_1+e_2$, so $$M=\pmatrix{0&1\cr-1&1\cr}$$ and $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $M$.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't active here. You posted later and I didnt care much later.. anyways  yep that seems like a good refutation.  Probably  my thing works only when the columns are the eigen vector space itself