# eigenvalues of $[T]^{B'}_{B}$ where $B'$ and $B$ are different bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V \to V$.

In my linear algebra class we proved the following statement: $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ IFF $λ$ is an eigenvalue for any matrix $A$ representing $T$.

However, we did actually prove this for any matrix $T$, we only proved it for matrices $A=[T]^{B}_{B}$ (Sometimes written $A=[T]_{BB}$)

But is it also true that $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ IFF $λ$ is an eigenvalue for any matrix $A$ representing $T$, where $A$ can be $[T]^{B'}_{B}$ with $B'$ and $B$ different bases?

I can't make sense of this discrepancy. It seems like every theorem we prove that is similar to the one above interprets  "any matrix $A$ representing $T$" to mean only matrices $A$ representing $T$ where $A=[T]^{B}_{B}$

Comment: In general, the eigenvalues of $[T]^{B'}_B$ will have nothing to do with the eigenvalues of $T$. In fact, if $T$ is any isomorphism, there will be bases $B, B'$ for $V$ such that $[T]^{B'}_B$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: This is the kind of response i'm looking for. Can you help me see this in a little more detail please?

Comment: Yes, here's a previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4204240/do-tee-and-tbe-have-the-same-eigenvalues/4204394#4204394) of mine on the subject.

Comment: How do you define eigenvalues of matrices in contrast to eigenvalues of linear maps?